# How to Call REST API with Body (form-data) and Params using POST method at same API? in Android Studio

Tags: android, rest, android-studio, mobile

I want to call an REST API with POST Method in which i want to pass body with form-data and Params at same call in API using Android Studio.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Do you mean that you want URL params *and* form-data params in the same request?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String body = """
        data={
            "username": "admin",
            "first_name": "System",
            "last_name": "Administrator"
        }
        """;
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(body,
    ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/register");
request.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

You need following imports:

```
package org.kodejava.apache.http;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
```

and depency:

```
<!--https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.jar-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hey, Thank for your answer but actually i want to upload an video to server using **multipart body form-data**  with video details that is **Query-Params**. with single API